# impossible to login with AJAX/ jquery login form

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, validation, authentication

I have a login form which works perfectly without the ajax part.
With the ajax/ jquery part it's not possibile to be redirected to the user account page because the error is always shown.

Html part:

```
<form id="loggin" action="<?php echo $action;?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="alto">
 <h3>Login</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="warning" style="display:none;"> <?php echo $error_warning; ?></div>    
 <?php if ($error_warning) { ?>
 <div class="warning"><?php echo $error_warning; ?></div>
 <?php } ?>
 <div>
 <label id="one" >Email:</label>
 <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"/>
 </div>
 <div>
 <label id="two">Password:</label>
 <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="<?php echo $password ?>"/>
 </div>
 <div class="basso">
 <input type="submit" value="Login"></input>
 <a href="#" class=" passwort linkform">Forgot Passoword?</a>
 <div class="clear"></div>
 </div>
 </form>
```

Ajax/ jquery part:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#loggin').submit(function(){                             
 email = $("#email").val(); 
 password = $("#password").val();
 $.ajax({
 url: 'index.php?dispatch=module/form',
 data: "email="+email+"&password="+password,
 success: function(some) {
 if(some=='true')    {
 window.location="index.php?dispatch=account/account";
 }else{
 $('.warning').css('display','block');
 $('#one,#two').css({
 color: 'red',
 fontWeight: 'bold'
 });
 $('#email,#password').addClass('errore22');
 }
 }
 }); return false;  //end ajax
 });          //end submit

 });
```

Where's the problem in the code?
Thanks in advance for helping.

**EDIT**

Maybe somebody knows another way to write the ajax part?

Comment: Have you included session_start(); at the beginning of your page? This should be declared at the beginning of all your pages

Comment: Like i said before, the php part is working perfectly, but the Ajax part doesn't :-(

Comment: Is the page redirecting after? If not then how is the php going to detect the cookie has now been set

Comment: @Liam with php the page will be redirect. But not with the ajax part, 'cause it will always show an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if(some=='true')    {

Maybe some just not equal 'true'? Also, to avoid errors you should always use var when declare new local variable.

Comment: Can you explain more please? Thanks! Why should "some" not equal to true?

Comment: According to jquery documentation:
"success
Type: Function( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. "

In another words, some - is an answer from php part. Are You sure that php part answers 'true'? Also I suggest use .post() instead of .ajax().

Comment: I tried with .post instead of .ajax, but it's not working. The most of  your explaining is too much for me, cannot understand it, because i'm pretty new in ajax/jquery. Instead, in my code i've added type: "POST", and after reloading the page it's working, but the form still not redirecting without manual reloading. **EDIT:** sure, 'some' returns true, without ajax it's working.

Comment: > EDIT: sure, 'some' returns true, without ajax it's working. You not understand one thing: some - is an answer from php. It can be some text or even object, not simple true or false. This is what your php script returns. Use alert(some) to know what it contains.

Comment: the alert contains the whole html login form (file .tpl). It is definitly not correct. So, how to write the code properly without the if/else statement ? **EDIT:** but the alert shows up only in the second part of the if/else.

Comment: You must rewrite php part. In example You can pass via ajax  some parameter (data: "email="+email+"&password="+password+"ajax=1") and check it on php side: if (isset($_POST['ajax'])) { /** short answer true or false **/} else { /** the whole page **/ }